# Using PHP to decode a string

Tags: php

I'm trying to decode a string using PHP but it doesn't seem to be returning the correct result.

I've tried using `html_entity_decode` as well as `utf8_decode(urldecode())`

Current code:

```
$str = "joh&#039;@test.com";
$decodeStr = html_entity_decode($str, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
```

Expected return is `john@test.com`

Comment: how did you encode it ? It seems your original string was `joh'@test.com`.

Comment: It was encoded by the cms that I'm using - im not sure of the specifics of the encoding.

Comment: without knowing the encoding rule, how can you decode it ?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose your html entity code for character 'n' is wrong.
Working example:

```
$str = "joh&#110;@test.com";
echo $decodeStr = html_entity_decode($str, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - no it's correct that it should be an apostrophe.

Comment: If "it's correct that it should be an apostrophe", how do we interpret your "Expected return is `john@test.com`"?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the entity for `@` be `&#064;` instead of `&#039;` which is for an apostrophe?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - no it's correct that it should be an apostrophe.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML entity code for `n` is `&#110;`, whereas the entity code in your string is for a single apostrophe `'`. If you wanted to convert single quotes, the `ENT_QUOTES` flag must be used when calling `html_entity_decode()`, as the default is `ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401` (from the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)) which doesn't convert single quotes. If you need additional flags, you can "add" them using the pipe `|` symbol like this: `ENT_HTML401 | ENT_QUOTES`.

If you're expecting `john@test.com`:

```
$str = "joh&#110;@test.com";
$decodeStr = html_entity_decode($str, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
echo $decodeStr;  // john@test.com
```

Or if you're expecting `joh'@test.com`:

```
$str = "joh&#039;@test.com";
$decodeStr = html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
echo $decodeStr; // joh'@test.com
```